# How to remove a chunk of XML from a file with AWK or SED

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

I'm an awk and sed newbie: When a line has the word 'Merry' I need to delete it and all other lines, inclusively, until I hit the word Merry again. Any ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Before:

```
<1 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<2 asjdasjgdakjsgd>

<3 Merry foo barrr >

<4 asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<5 asjdasjgdakjsgd>

<6 / Merry foo barrr >

<7 asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<8 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
```

After:

```
<1 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<2 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<4 asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<5 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<7 asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<8 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
```

Comment: Before and After are the same.

Comment: Thanks- sorry about the confusion. I've updated the data

Comment: `When a line has the word 'Merry' I need to delete it and all other lines, inclusively,`　what are `all other lines`?

Comment: Please make the generic lines different from each other (add 1, 2, 3 … for example).  Your sample output seems to include the lines between the original start and end 'Merry' lines — is it supposed to?  Are blank lines to be deleted everywhere?  Is the 'XML' tag actually spelled with spaces around the words in it?  Does 'Merry' only appear in the tag or can it appear in other lines too?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I have now updated the data and question based on recommendations

Comment: @larsks you are right, but with a bad example. "in terms of XML syntax", element name doesn't allow to have spaces or linebreaks.

Comment: Don't try to manipulate XML with awk or sed, because XML is not itself line-based (e.g., `<foo bar="1" baz="2">` is identical, in terms of XML syntax, to `<foo\nbar="1"\nbaz="2">`).

Comment: @user1654528 :  do you actually need the `<4 asjdasjgdakjsgd> ` & `<5 asjdasjgdakjsgd>` in the output? If your objective is to delete the lines from the starting to the ending tag, my answer might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your requirement and input, this one-liner works:

```
kent$  sed '/Merry\|^\s*$/d' file 
<1 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<2 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<4 asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<5 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<7 asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<8 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
```

### add an awk one-liner:

```
kent$  awk 'NF&&!/Merry/' file
<1 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<2 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<4 asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<5 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<7 asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<8 asjdasjgdakjsgd>
```

Comment: Hi, I've just this on my Mac using the data above and your generously provided statement: sed '/Merry\|^\s*$/d' file1 > file2. When I try this file2 ends up with the same data as file1. Would you mind double checking the statement please?

Comment: @user1654528 I don't have bsd sed and don't have mac either. The line was tested with gnu sed. anyway, I added an awk one-liner. should work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Had the input (stored in the file merry) been :

```
<1asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<2asjdasjgdakjsgd>

< Merry foo barrr >

<3asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<4asjdasjgdakjsgd>

< /Merry foo barrr >

<5asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<6asjdasjgdakjsgd>
< Merry foo barrr >

<7asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<8asjdasjgdakjsgd>

< / Merry foo barrr >
```

and your objective were to delete the lines from the opening merry tag to ending merry tag, you might do something like below :

```
sed '/Merry/{:label1;N;/\/.*Merry/!b label1;d};' merry
```

which gives me this output :

```
<1asjdasjgdakjsgd>
<2asjdasjgdakjsgd>


<5asjdasjgdakjsgd> 
<6asjdasjgdakjsgd>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a range of lines using sed like

```
sed -r '/Merry/,/Merry/{d}
```